# Functions not overriding with multiple levels of extended classes

Tags: php, class, oop, extend, extends

I'm running out of ideas for troubleshooting an issue with functions not overriding those from the classes they extend. Hopefully someone here has some more ideas to try.

I'll try to explain the issue in as generic of a way as possible while trying not to leave out details that might be important...so here it goes.

Here's an example representing the basic structure:

```
//For functionality common to every area of site
// in A.class.php
abstract class A{
    $called_class='';
    function __construct(){
        $this->called_class=get_called_class();
    }
    function foo(){
        echo "Apple";
    }
    function bar(){
        $this->foo();
    }
}

//Some specialized functionality
// in B.class.php
class B extends A{
    function foo(){
        echo "Grapefruit";
    }
}

//Specialized functionality for another area of site.
//This area has several distinct but related sub-parts,
// so C1 is for functionality common to those sub-parts
// in C1.class.php
abstract class C1 extends A{
    function foo(){
        echo "Orange";
    }
}
//For specialized functionality unique to each sub-part
// in C2.class.php
class C2 extends C1{
    function someotherstuff(){
        echo "Pear";
    }
}
```

Classes A, B, C1, and C2 are in separate files (A.class.php, B.class.php, etc) and I use an autoload function which knows how to locate the class files based on the class name.

Using the example above, when I instantiate 'C2' and call foo() I expect to get back "Orange", and when I run the example above that's exactly what happens.

```
//WHEN CLASSES ARE ALL CONTAINED IN SAME FILE:
$x = new C2();
$x->foo();  //Displays "Orange"
echo $x->called_class; //Displays "C2"
```

However, in practice, the behavior of $x->foo() is to display "Apple" instead of "Orange".
In practice, the behavior of class B is just as it should be. Only the "C" branch seems to have problems.

```
//WHEN CLASSES ARE INCLUDED FROM MULTIPLE SEPARATE FILES:
$x = new C2();
$x->foo();  //Displays "Apple"
echo $x->called_class; //Still displays "C2"
```

I tried to reproduce the issue by combining copies of each class' source code into a single file, but surprisingly it worked exactly as it should when in a single file.

My next thought was that for some reason I was instantiating the wrong class, so I started calling "get_called_class()" in the constructor of class A and storing the value. However, this always returns the value I expect it to ("C2", in the context of this example).

Does anyone have any ideas why an instance of class C2 would use the foo() function from class A instead of from class C1, which C2 extends? (Why it would return "Apple" instead of "Orange")

**Edit:** Here is my autoload function boiled down to the relevant bits. All testing I've done has indicated that the function I use is loading the correct files.

```
public static function autoload($className) {
     $fileName=sprintf('%s.class.php',$className);

     $filePathsToCheck=array();

     //Check For Local Version
     $filePathsToCheck[] = PATH_TO_FOLDER_DEDICATED_TO_THIS_SITE.'classes/');

     //Check for Shared version
     $filePathsToCheck[] = PATH_TO_FOLDER_COMMON_TO_MULTIPLE_SITES.'classes/';

     foreach($filePathsToCheck as $filePath){
         if(file_exists($filePath.$fileName)){
            include_once $filePath.$fileName;
            break;
         }
     }

}
```

Comment: Are you sure that you do not have another class with this name?

Comment: Are you sure this is your only code? You are talking about an autoload function. Can you show it?

Comment: I don't understand your exemples. Both define a new C2(), you say that both are behaving correctly but the same code `$x = new C2()` generates two different things?? is your first exemple `new C1()` by any chance?

Comment: @sectus - Yes, I'm confident the classes are unique. In the actual code, the classes have very unique names which correspond to the file they are contained within (1 class per file). Files are only loaded when the relevant class is called if it has not been loaded yet. Using this structure, if I did somehow end up with a duplicate class name, the extra copy _should_ never load.

Comment: @S.Pols - I added a boiled-down version of the autoload function I use. Yes, there is _significantly_ more code that is used to generate each page, but nothing that should be relevant to the example.  

I thought perhaps someone would recognize this scenario as a qwerk in how PHP handles includes. When I get time perhaps I'll try putting together an independent set of files I can share that exhibit the issue.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier - Yes, sort of. The first example includes comments which indicate the output when all the classes are in a single file, while the comments in the second indicate the output is when the classes are loaded from separate files.